# LightningChartJs point series disappears after changing angular route

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, lightningchart

I'm using `LightningChartJs 2.0.2` in my `Angular` application.

In the chart I have a line and a point series implemented, what works like expected.

But if I change the route and come back to the chart `the point series is not visible anymore`. Tried with different environments without success. I'm also not able to locate the reason of the actual issue.

Following code shows the creation of the chart and series:

```
this.chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({container: `${this.chartId}`});

const lineSeries = this.chart.addLineSeries().setStrokeStyle((style) => style.setThickness(5));
   
lineSeries.add(this.points);

const pointSeries = this.chart.addPointSeries().setName('Points').setPointSize(6);

pointSeries.add(this.points);
```

On destroy the chart is disposed:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    // "dispose" should be called when the component is unmounted to free all the resources used by the chart
    this.chart.dispose();
  }
```

Normally the chart and all depenendencies will be destroyd at this point.
If I come back to the chart page the chart should be new created with all it's series, but the point series isn't.

**Why the point series is not visible anymore and how to fix it?**

Please see the stackblitz example! The chart handling is located in

```
/src/app/lc-test/lc-test.component.ts
```

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Change the route to `LC Test`. You see the line and point series.
2. Change back to `Dashboard` and again to `LC-Test`. The line series is visible and the point series not.

Used Chrome and Firefox on Mac.

[lightningChart Js - stackblitz - point series disappears on route change issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gahc54?file=src/app/lc-test/lc-test.component.ts)

After playing a bit with the zoom options it looks like there is a rendering issue on the point series:

Normal behavior:

[image]

After route change and zoom into top section:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a rendering issue in LightningChart JS v2.0.2. We have now fixed it in a v2.0.3 release. Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention.

With LightningChart JS v2.0.3 the app you provided is working as expected.